# Pushing new code to elasticbeanstalk deletes old production log

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services

Whenever I push new code to elasticbeanstalk app on aws, all the rails production log are deleted and the file is rewritten. Is there any way, I can change app configuration not to delete them or any other method people use to store all logs in which new code don't delete them?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can roll the logs to S3 before a new deployment.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.loggingS3.title.html